# HKObserverQuery in Health Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, healthkit

In which format does `HKObserverQuery` gets data?
There is no `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to store data then how to get.
I am putting the query put not able to get all data, anyone please help?

```
HKObserverQuery *query =
[[HKObserverQuery alloc]
 initWithSampleType:object
 predicate:Predicate
 updateHandler:^(HKObserverQuery *query,
                 HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler completionHandler,
                 NSError *error) {
[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"]];


     if (error) {

         // Perform Proper Error Handling Here...
         NSLog(@"*** An error occured while setting up the stepCount observer. %@ ***",
               error.localizedDescription);
         abort();
     }
     else{
         NSLog(@"@%",query);
         }

 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKObserverQuery` is not intended to deliver data to your app. The `updateHandler` is simply called whenever a `HKSample` matching your predicate is added or removed from HealthKit. It is then up to your app to perform additional queries in response, such as `HKSampleQuery` or `HKStatisticsQuery`.

Comment: Can I use HKAnchoredQuery and HKObserverQuery in a same code?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing that would prevent you from doing that.

Comment: Allan, Why I am getting problem in this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277821/hkanchoredquery-update-handler-not-working-properly/36279850?noredirect=1#comment60241537_36279850, please solve this?